# set a layout for certain actions?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

My app/views/layouts folder looks like this:

```
application.html.erb
user_sessions.html.erb
errors.html.erb
```

These work fine and i have no problems with them but id now like to add a new layout for tips, but only on the index and show actions.

Would "tips.index.html.erb" work?

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Add a new layout as you like called 'tips.html.erb'

In the tips controller add the following:

```
layout "tips", :only => [ :index, :show ]
```

You can specify the layout for a specific action using:

```
def new 
    render(:layout => "layouts/application")
end
```

I have never tried using multiple layout declarations in a controller. It might be that adding another

```
layout "standard", :only => [ :new, :edit ]
```

might work...

Comment: It's worth mentioning, that you can _not_ call `layout` multiple times in the
controller, as only the last call will be evaluated. Instead (in rails 4 at
least), you can call `layout` passing a method's symbol. The method can then
dynamically return different template names. See
[layout](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/AbstractController/Layouts/ClassMethods.html#method-i-layout).

Answer (score 7):

If you want to use multiple layout in a controller, use the code below: ( action_name is a pre-defined variable that you could use directly in Rails)

```
class OrdersController < BaseController
  layout :determine_layout

private
  def determine_layout
    %w(new).include?(action_name) ? "some_layout" : "public"
  end
end
```

see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5525014/445908