# Use a layout for a specific action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If I would like to use a layout for a certain action (say, the show action) that is different from the layout declared at the top of the controller.rb file, how could I do this? This must be possible in rails, but I cannot seem to find anything about it.

Comment: +1 and I agree the Rails documentation is a hell.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

```
  render :layout => 'otherlayout'
```

Comment: accepting this answer as it answers the specific question I asked, but both answers are good and achieve the goal

Comment: +1: As I said, Don's is right, too. And +1 for this being like, the least trolling community I've ever been a part of. Everyone is more concerned about being productive than right. When Internet 2.0 comes out, this should be the primary concept.

Answer (score 37):

```
layout 'layout', :only => [:first_action, :second_action]
layout 'second_layout', :only => [:third_action, :fourth_action]
```

Don's is right as well, just depends on your application which is more DRY (or DRY-er?)

---

**EDIT** 
My previous code is mistaken. You cannot specify the `layout` function multiple times. I found this solution online for dynamic layout rendering:

```
class OrdersController < BaseController
  layout :determine_layout

private
  def determine_layout
    %w(new).include?(action_name) ? "some_layout" : "public"
  end
end
```

> Source: [apidock.com/rails/Actio...](http://apidock.com/rails/ActionController/Layout/ClassMethods/layout#note_info-851)

Comment: +1:  This is better if you have layouts to apply to multiple actions.

Comment: Rails doesn't seem to accept multiple layout specifications per file. You can specify :only a, b, c but you can't then specify another set with different targets.

Answer (score 0):

Following example applies desired layout to specific action, otherwise, it uses default layout (layouts/application.html.erb).

```
class ArticlesController < ApplicationController
   layout "article_editor", only: [:new, :edit]

   def index
     # default layout
   end

   def new
     # article_editor layout
   end

   def edit
     # article_editor layout
   end
end
```