# How do I use a different Layout for a specific :action?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Ruby 1.8.7, Rails 2.3.11

I've been trying the [answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5524924/use-a-layout-for-a-specific-action) that appear to be what I'm asking about already, but neither worked successfully for me (probably because I'm relatively new to Rails and wasn't understanding them correctly).

I'm trying to create a printer-friendly view for a model (posters), which will be accessible at /posters/print/1.  How can I have the print action use a different layout file than index, new, edit, and show?

One answer said `render :layout => 'otherlayout'`, which I put in the print controller method to make `format.xml  { render :layout => 'print', :xml => @poster }`.  That didn't change anything when I refreshed (after clearing my cache) the page.

The other answer said

```
layout 'layout', :only => [:first_action, :second_action]
layout 'second_layout', :only => [:third_action, :fourth_action]
```

which I put at the top of the poster controller file like so:

```
layout 'posters', :only => [:show, :edit, :index]
layout 'print', :only => [:print]
```

but that appears to only use the latter line (show, edit, and index are rendered directly from their own .html.erb files, rather that wrapped inside the poster layout).

Please let me know if I need to post more information.

Comment: Why are you trying to apply the layout to your xml format?

Comment: Umm... I had it before the format commands, but it threw an error saying that render could only be called once per action, so I threw in with the only place that render appeared.  ><

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of methods you can use. One is the layouts the other is via css. Rather than having another page load and db call I would opt for the CSS method which is not hard, just change the media type to print so it looks like this:

```
stylesheet_link_tag 'print', :media => 'print'
```

For the layouts have you tried:

```
def print
  layout 'print'
end
```

Comment: Thanks for responding so quickly!

The stylesheet_link_tag is a step closer to what I'm looking for.  This might be more of a CSS question now, but how would I get rid of elements that don't need to be printed  from this print view?  I don't need things like the navigation links to be displayed, and I'm not sure how to make them disappear with just a change in stylesheet.

When I put I added layout 'print' to the print action in my poster controller, nothing happened.  Was that the correct location?

Answer (score 1):

When you're rendering XML, it doesn't get a layout, because it's rendering XML, which doesn't use a view.

For what you're trying to do, you could simply create a printer stylesheet using `stylesheet_link_tag('print', :media => :print)` in your layout. This will automatically get used by the browser when you print.

Comment: Thanks - that's a step closer to what I'm looking for.  This might be more of a CSS question now, but how would I get rid of elements that don't need to be printed  from this print view?  I don't need things like the navigation links to be displayed, and I'm not sure how to make them disappear with just a change in stylesheet.

Comment: `#nav { display:none; }` should do it.