# Printing stuff in rails (literally to a printer)

Tags: javascript, html, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I'm wondering if there was any library or gem available in Rails for printing the contents of a web page, as in literally on to paper via a printer. I was also wondering if there was any way you can specify that only a specific part of the page (e.g. a div or something) would be printed? Any pointers, advice, or links to tutorials would be appreciated!

**EDIT**

so I've made a stab at creating a stylesheet which will create a print friendly view, let's call it "print.css":

```
div.transpose-keys, div#editSong, div#navigation, div#debug{
    display: none;
}
```

And I was wondering if there was any way I could apply it only when my application fires the print action? So that when the following is link is clicked 
the application applies the css above before it prints? Here's the link in my embedded ruby html:

```
<%= link_to "PRINT", '#', onclick: "printpage()" %>
```

And finally my javascript calling the print function:

```
function printpage()
  {
  window.print()
  }
```

Comment: Might want to look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6406425/how-do-i-use-a-different-layout-for-a-specific-action

Answer (score 14, accepted):

If you add your print.css as follows

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" media="print" href="print.css">
```

and use browser print dialog, it should automatically format the page according to the style in print.css

Answer (score 7):

I got around my problem by using this simple solution:

**print.css**:

```css
@media print {
  div.info, div#editStuff, div#navigation, div#debug {
    display: none;
  }
}
```

the @media tag ensures these are *not* displayed in the printed version

**application.js**:

```js
function printpage()
{
   window.print()
}
```

**show.html.erb**:

```erb
<%= link_to "PRINT", '#', onclick: "printpage()" %>
```

Comment: so the difference between what you were trying in your `EDIT`, and this solution, is adding `@media.print { }` around the print.css? May want to format this answer better (the @media.print is not formatted properly)

Comment: is it supposed to apply `print.css` at the print-preview, or only in the printed doc? It's not quite working for me

Answer (score 3):

I believe the way this is generally done is to open up a 'printer friendly' window with only the desired info on it, and from there the user prints through their web browser. You could make it a bit more user-friendly by adding some javascript in that window:

```
window.print();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<script type="text/javascript">     
        function PrintDiv() {    
           var divToPrint = document.getElementById('divToPrint');
           var popupWin = window.open('', '_blank', 'width=300,height=300');
           popupWin.document.open();
           popupWin.document.write('<html><body onload="window.print()">' + divToPrint.innerHTML + '</html>');
            popupWin.document.close();
                }
     </script>
```

```
<%= image_tag("print.jpg", :width=>50, :height=>30, :onclick=>"PrintDiv();", :class=>'btn') %>
```

Answer (score 1):

I use wkhtmltopdf, http://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/, and PDFKit, http://railscasts.com/episodes/220-pdfkit.

The RailsCast is going to have a complete example while the wkhtmltopdf is a rack utility that grabs and outputs a PDF document.