# Turbolinks and css classes applied to html tags

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, turbolinks

My HTML tags have classes defined to identify the correct layout.

```
<html class="one-column">
```

This becomes an issue with [Turbolinks](https://github.com/rails/turbolinks) as it only refreshes the `body` and `title` tags.

> ... it keeps the current page instance alive and replaces only the body and the title in the head.

This means the HTML class is not changing when I transition from pages with a `one-column` to pages with `two-column` classes.

How do I get around this? I can't apply the class names to the body.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The whole purpose of **Tubolinks** is not to load the entire DOM with every request. The `html` tag being at the top of the DOM, changing its attributes (e.g. *class*) means that its children should also be invalidated. So it kind of beats the purpose of **Turbolinks**. You can either disable **Turbolinks** entirely, as pointed out [here](http://blog.steveklabnik.com/posts/2013-06-25-removing-turbolinks-from-rails-4), or you can move the *class* to the body, which should work. Why is it actually not possible for you to move it to the body?

Answer (score -1):

Why don't you [change the `layout`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2101806/set-a-layout-for-certain-actions)?

The reason why you're current implementation isn't working is because it's a hack. CSS class styles are meant to style individual elements, not the whole page

What if the page is rendered *without* the `<HTML>` tag for some reason? Your styles would be defunct

---

**Layouts**

An extensible way to handle this will be to change the **layout** depending on what you're doing. Here's how I would do it:

```
#app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<html>
    <!-- Default Styling Here -->
</html>

#app/views/layouts/action.html.erb
<html>
    <!-- Other Styling  -->
</html>

#app/controllers/your_controller.rb
layout "action", :only => [ :index, :show ]
```

Layouts are independent of Turbolinks (they are HTML), which means you can load them as many times as you need

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I already have different layouts. Your solution does not work because, when the layout changes, Trubolinks doesn't update the `html` node, so the class name remains the unchanged.

Comment: Thanks for the comment! My solution isn't to take your example & put it into different layouts. Styling the <html> tag is not considered good practice (for this very reason), and so I'd recommend using the different layouts to create a different style structure for each. This way, you can change the style dynamically, without hindering turbolinks